# Mechanical Rigging w/ physics

Tags: rigging, armature, physics

I'm rigging a jet drone (jets on the end of mechanical legs that are attached to a cube) and I would like for it to actually have physics.

Below is the model and rigging:
[image: Hoverlegs w/rigging]

I'd like for it to be that the jets actually lift up the cube, and for the legs to bend/rotate their parts accordingly.
Not exactly sure how I can do this, I've tried everything so far.

Here's my .blend file:
[image]